# Extract data from Sql to Excel in Specific Format

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I want to extract data from tables in given format, currently i am using

`System.Data.DataTable` to get data from database using function given below(DBhelerp returns DataTable)

```
public void GetData()
{
dgvResult.DataSource=new DBHelper.GetTable("Select * from Candidate c inner join Qualification q on ( q.candidateId=c.CandidateId)");
}
```

assign result to `dgvResult.DataSource` and than

copying this data to excel using following function

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
        {

                dgvResult.SelectAll();
                DataObject dataObj = dgvResult.GetClipboardContent();
                if (dataObj != null)
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);

        }
```

and it gives following result.

[image]

My question is that how may get data in given(specified) format(Result Table in Image).

> One more thing I don't want to use any Library(i.e Excel) just want to do with
>   default controls.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you.

```
Excel.Application excel= new Excel.Application(); 


private System.Data.DataTable GetData()
{
SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(@"server=(local)\vste;uid=sa;pwd=;database=northwind;");
SqlDataAdapter adapter= new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Customers",conn);
DataSet myDataSet= new DataSet();
try {
adapter.Fill(myDataSet,"Customer");
}
catch(Exception ex) {
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
return myDataSet.Tables[0];
} 


foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
{
colIndex++; excel.Cells[1,colIndex]=col.ColumnName;
}
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) {
rowIndex++; colIndex=0;
foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
colIndex++; excel.Cells[rowIndex,colIndex]=row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check one of the following links

http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx

http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/

Comment: I really do not how some people downvote, the same answer is accepted and up-voted in another question! seems that some people has the down-vote syndrome!!!!!

Comment: your answer is valid but not in this situation.I don't want to use Excel Lib/Package.
I want to do this task using default control(s)

Comment: @EdwardIslam pls mention this in ur question